# Will Wi-Fi Direct allow me to connect to an ad-hoc network?

Tags: htc-one-x, ad-hoc-networks, wifi-direct

I have been trying to connect my HTC One X to an ad-hoc wireless network, so I could browse Internet on my phone. I found Android doesn't support ad-hoc networking and I noticed on some pages that Wi-Fi Direct is better than ad-hoc anyway. How can I connect my computer with Windows XP to my mobile using Wi-Fi Direct?

When I open the Wi-Fi direct settings, it shows nothing although I search for network.

What is the process? Is there any other way I can connect to an ad-hoc network?

Comment: It looks like this [link](http://androidforums.com/android-lounge/552970-howto-wifi-direct-use-your-laptop-desktop-softap-android-reverse-tethering.html) (Sorry requires account to view images) might apply to @hsuk situation. I would summarize, but it is long and has images. It is using Intel MyWiFi and WiFi Direct.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, WiFi Direct is for Peer to Peer WiFi connection only, like paring with Buetooth. Your PC isn't set up to do this kind of direct connection.
So the answer is "no".
Your question is mixed, what did you use to create the ad-hoc network? What was the route that would allow you to brwose the web?
You can use an HTC One X to create a WiFi hotspot for the PC to connect to, but not the other way around.
It's  really confusing question.

Comment: Thanks, @martino, actually, I read somewhere like wifi direct is more efficient alternative of ad-hoc. Actually I wanted to connect my mobile to a ad hoc connection from computer. Since I could not do it directly, I was searching for ways to do that and asking whether wifi direct can be the way.

Comment: It's a fair question. Thx for the bump!